# background size white bottom

Tags: html, css

whenever I do background-size:cover it covers the whole screen which is nice but it leaves a white bottom is there any fix to this?

```
body {  background-image:url("maxresdefault.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Comment: try put  `height: 100vh;` or  `height: 100%;`

Comment: show the issue in fiddle/snippet

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `height`
So:

```
body {  
    background-image:url("maxresdefault.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be a few things causing this, I'd suggest making a plunker for it.

I'd guess those options: if there is some kind of tag that has a margin on it (like h1 or p) at the bottom, put it with `margin: 0;`.

Try:

```
body {
background-image:url("maxresdefault.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin: 0;
}
```

Try setting the height like people suggested above.